# How do I tell if the browser window is Maximized in Silverlight/C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight

How do I tell if the browser window is Maximized in Silverlight/C#?

The "Form" maximize feature will not work because I am writing a silverlight app that runs in the browser.

I have tried this:

App.Current.Host.Content.FullScreenChanged += new EventHandler(Content_FullScreenChanged);

but this event handler is not called when I maximize the window.

Maximized is not full screen

App.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen;

returns false even if I maximize the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser does not pass that kind of information down to its content.

You can probably detect a resize event and then compare the browser window size with the screen size with some tolerance for the browser borders... however you will never be able to be sure if that is maximized.

Comment: In that case, is there a way of doing a system metrics query and get the size of the window, and then compare that to the current size of the app window?

Comment: silverlight can interoperate with javascript, you can detect window size through javascript then pass down to the silverlight app which can compare to the screen size.

Comment: or I can get the windows on resize event too.  The browser might not pass all the information down.  But Maybe I can get what I need.  Are there ways of getting the screen resolution in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

The IsFullScreen is unrelated to browser size. Think of that being more like when you make your media player full-size (the smaller window still exists under it).

Here is a link showing various properties of the browser you can access with Silverlight. It is old but still relevant:

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/06/browserscreeninformation/

Comment: Are there ways of getting the screen resolution in Silverlight? This information will help me in finding out of the app has been maximized.